# Is there any way to trace Cloud SQL calls in App Engine? (Golang)

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-trace

As title suggests, I would like to trace Cloud SQL calls in App Engine (Golang) Standard Environment.

I found that there is [Java library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40002975/is-there-any-way-to-trace-cloud-sql-calls-in-app-engine) for that.  Is there anything like that for Golang?

Answer (score 2):

https://cloud.google.com/trace/docs/setup/go

This is a default tracing library from google. In our app it's logging number of actions in the app, like calls to log writes, calls to Datastore and to SQL as well. Just install it and go to Trace in Cloud Console. Make an request to your endpoint, and you will see in this Trace tab information about the request and it's components. You also will be able to manually add custom tracing events (some custom logic execution time of which you want to trace).

Comment: As per doc, I think it is not supported in standard edition. `On Google App Engine standard environment, the trace package is not currently supported.`